# Sql pivot query with complex aggregation

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I've got some problems with a pivot query (SQL Server).
The task is quite simple: for a person I have to collect it's income stats for every month in a year but every new month income is based on the `previuos income` plus the `current month income`

Just for example. Let a person have a 3k salary per month (for simplicity it's a constant) then a query result should be something like this:

```
Year | Jan | Feb | ... | Dec
2016 | 3k  | 6k  | ... | 36k
2015 | 3k  | 6k  | ... | 36k
...
```

A pseudo SQL query is:

```
select * from (
    select 
        year(date) as year,
        month(date) as month
        salary,
    from income
    where personId = 'some id'
) as tmp
pivot (
    sum(salary),
    for month in ([1], [1..2], [1..3], ...)
) as pvt
```

The problem is there's no [1..2] expression in SQL.
What's the way to perform such query using a standard SQL?

Comment: Just some off the top of my head hints:inner query to partition and sum using a suitable window (between rows unbounded preceding and current?), with a label for your period 1to2, 1to3, 1to4 etc Then pivot on your labels. If I've time later tonight I'll have a look at a full solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this? (this [OVER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461(v=sql.105).aspx) will work for version 2008 R2 and after)

```
create table #income (
    personid int,
    salary int,
    [date] date
)

insert into #income 
(personid,salary,[date])
values
(1,3000,'2016-01-31'),
(1,3000,'2016-02-29'),
(1,3000,'2016-03-31'),
(1,3000,'2016-04-30'),
(1,3000,'2016-05-31');

select * from (
    select 
        year(date) as year,
        month(date) as month,
        SUM(salary) OVER ( PARTITION BY personid ORDER BY [date]) salary
    from income
    where personId = 1
) as tmp
pivot (
    sum(salary)
    for month in ([1], [2], [3],[4],[5])
) as pvt;

drop table #income;
```

Comment: If there's a previous year values it affects next year results.

Comment: I think PARTITION BY personid, year(date) ORDER BY [date] should suffice your requirement.